# Changing camera axis

Tags: game-engine

I'm making a game in blender but as you know when I rotate a camera the Y axis becomes the vertical and the Z becomes the forward/back. Is there a way to rotate it but keep the axis like Z is vertical and Y is forward/back?

Comment: If you can't apply rotation, can you parent it to an empty with proper rotation and work with that?

Comment: One way you could do this is by constraining it's location to an unrotated empty

Comment: Are constraining and parenting different, or just the same solution? @NoviceInDisguise

Comment: Pretty much the same thing, but you can animate the strength of a constraint

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Won't parenting copy the rotation too? (Not that it matters in this case, as long as you avoid rotating the empty)

Comment: I've solved it - as @NoviceInDisguise said, I simply parented the camera to an empty and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is parent the rotated camera to an **unrotated** empty using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. Now you can animate or manipulate the empty and the camera will follow it exactly, while retaining it's rotation.